# Calculate mean & var numpy genfromtxt dataframe - TypeError ufunc add

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror, numpy-ufunc

I have simple text files containing floating numbers, e.g.:

```
3.235235
0.2346236
1.235235
```

I'm trying to calculate mean & variance for every file using the following code:

```
import numpy
import os

def main():
    for filename in os.listdir("./"):
        try:
            df = numpy.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter='\n', usecols=(0))
            with open(filename, "a") as newfile:
                newfile.write("\nMean: " + numpy.mean(df) + "\n")
                newfile.write("\Variance: " + numpy.var(df) + "\n")
                newfile.close()

        except IOError:
            print "Error reading file: %r\n" % filename

        except ValueError:
            print "Non-numeric data found in the file: %r\n" % filename         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But I get the following error:

```
newfile.write("\nMean: " + numpy.mean(df) + "\n")
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

When observing the `df` it looks like:

```
df.dtype = float64
df.shape = (3577,)
```

Moreover, when using python cli and running:

```
df = numpy.genfromtxt("arp_40000_host_0.txt", delimiter='\n', usecols=(0))
numpy.mean(df)
```

I get no errors, so it seems the problem is with the `write` back to the file??

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I've updated the post. it seems the problem is within the `write` statement, not sure what the problem is :\

Answer (score 0):

Problem was results from `numpy.mean()` and `numpy.var()` couldn't be concatenated to a string.

Wrapping the results with `str()` solved it.